# Secure String.to_int and others

Tags: opa

I use String.to_int, and some time i get errors, for example when the string is not a representation of an int. I would like to catch these errors, or test parameter before to use the function. Some ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm, one could argue that it would have been better if `String.to_int` from the stdlib returned an optional integer (`none` indicating an error).

However, in Opa most parsing is done using [parsers](http://opalang.org/resources/book/index.html#section_syntax_trex)*. For instance to get the aforementioned function you could write:

```
string_to_int_opt(s : string) : option(int) =
  Parser.try_parse(Rule.integer, s)
```

or, if you want to be less verbose the equivalent:

```
string_to_int_opt = Parser.try_parse(Rule.integer, _)
```

or if it's part of the more complex parsing you would just use the `Rule.integer` parser there.

(*) I guess this section of the manual could use some extensions...